# Predict Future values using polynomial regression in R

Tags: r, regression, prediction, forecasting

Was trying to predict the future value of a sample using polynomial regression in R. The y values within the sample forms a wave pattern.
For example

```
x = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
y= 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,4
```

But when the graph is plotted for future values the resultant `y` values was completely different from what was expected. Instead of a wave pattern, was getting a graph where the `y` values keep increasing.

```
futurY = 17,18,19,20,21,22
```

Tried different degrees of polynomial regression, but the predicted results for `futurY` were drastically different from what was expected

Following is the sample R code which was used to get the results

```
dfram <- data.frame('x'=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
dfram$y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,4)
plot(dfram,dfram$y,type="l", lwd=3)
pred <- data.frame('x'=c(17,18,19,20,21,22))
myFit <- lm(y ~ poly(x,5), data=dfram)
newdata <- predict(myFit, pred)
print(newdata)
plot(pred[,1],data.frame(newdata)[,1],type="l",col="red", lwd=3)
```

Is this the correct technique to be used for predicting the unknown future y values OR should I be using other techniques like forecasting?

Comment: Trying to predict with a fifth order polynomial looks doomed for failure or confusion. You might want to do some searching on fitting trig functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Reproducing your data frame
dfram <- data.frame("x" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16),
                    "y" = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,4))
```

From your graph I've got the phase and period of the signal. There're better ways of calculating that automatically.

```
# Phase and period
fase = 1
per = 10
```

In the linear model function I've put the triangular signal equations.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ I((((trunc((x-fase)/(per/2))%%2)*2)-1) * (x-fase)%%(per/2))
            + I((((trunc((x-fase)/(per/2))%%2)*2)-1) * ((per/2)-((x-fase)%%(per/2))))
          ,data=dfram)

# Predict the old data
p_olddata <- predict(fit,type="response")

# Predict the new data
newdata <- data.frame('x'=c(17,18,19,20,21,22))
p_newdata <- predict(fit,newdata,type="response")

# Ploting Old and new data
plot(x=c(dfram$x,newdata$x),
     y=c(p_olddata,p_newdata),
     col=c(rep("blue",length(p_olddata)),rep("green",length(p_olddata))),
     xlab="x",
     ylab="y")
lines(dfram)
```

[image]

Where the black line is the original signal, the blue circles are the prediction for the original points and the green circles are the prediction for the new data.

The graph shows a perfect fit for the model because there's no noise in the data. In a real dataset you may find it so the fit will not look as nice as that.

Comment: generous of you to take the time! Still, you could warn OP that polys are fine for interpolation, lousy for extrapolation (prediction), and it's time to move on to better approaches.

Comment: Thanks for putting in your time. This helped me to point to the correct direction. So can I confirm that polynomial regression cannot be used for such cases.

Comment: Thanks @sisusisu. When you have signals that show repetitive cycles, polynomial regression may not be the best option. Trigonometric functions of mathematical series may be what you look for.